# Can I use a SelectList in a VisualForce email template?

Tags: visualforce-component, email-template, visualforce-template

I have a VisualForce email template which is used to send a list of products to customers. The products are listed in a table in the email and I would like the end column to be a picklist with options the customer should choose from when they reply to the email as per the image below.

[image]

It looks good in the preview, but as soon as I send it it arrives like this.

[image]

This my component which is called by the VF template:

```
<apex:component controller="ConsignmentsOutstandingController" access="global">
   <apex:attribute name="acId" assignTo="{!aId}" type="String" description="the account id"/>
   <hr/>
   <!--<apex:dataTable>-->
   <table border="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%" id="table3" style="font-size:11px;">
       <tr>
           <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><b>Document Date</b></td>
           <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><b>Order</b></td>
           <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><b>Product</b></td>
           <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><b>Description</b></td>
           <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><b>Quantity</b></td>
           <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><b>Action(I/R/C)</b></td>
      </tr>
      <apex:repeat value="{!cons}" var="oi">
         <tr>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{0, date, yyyy-mm-dd}">
                    <apex:param value="{!oi.Order.EffectiveDate}" /> 
                </apex:outputText>
            </td>
            <!--<td>{!oi.Order.EffectiveDate}</td>-->
            <td>{!oi.Order.Name}</td>
            <td>{!oi.PriceBookEntry.Product2.ProductCode}</td>
            <td>{!oi.PriceBookEntry.Product2.Name}</td>
            <td>{!oi.Quantity}</td>
            <td>
                <select id="actionOption" name="ActionOption" size="1">
                    <option value="continue">Continue</option>
                    <option value="invoice">Invoice</option>
                    <option value="return">Return</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>  
</table>
<!--</apex:dataTable>-->
```

Comment: The above works in Gmail, but not in Outlook :(